# How to: Background Processing of WooCommerce Product Batch API calls

Tags: wordpress, api, woocommerce

I'm running a webshop with 7000 products. Every night I'm executing a cronjob on my ERP-system, pushing all product-information into my WooCommerce store through their Restful API.

This works perfectly... However, I'm looking for ways to improve the performance of this task.

What I've done, so far, is to change my individual update API requests to a [batch](https://woocommerce.github.io/woocommerce-rest-api-docs/#batch-update-products) call. Thereby I limit my requests from 7000 to around 1400 - I can batch around 50 products without running into gateway timeouts and other serverside limitations.

However, while improving this, I'm wondering if there are some smart way of scheduling these update-tasks into a background queue/process. I'm quite familiar with this on Laravel, but I'm wondering if anything exist in Wordpress/WooCommerce that actually supports this out-of-the-box.

What I actually mean; instead of executing the update-batch task upon API-call, the API should just schedule the task and send a response back to client, telling that the task has been added succesfully. This way the ERP-system dosen't have to wait for the WooCommerce to finalize the whole batch. If I make the ERP-system make async calls, then it would properly lead to overloading the WooCommerce, and wouldn't be beneficial.

If not, what would actually be the best approach to accomplish this? I'm thinking of making an jobs/queue-databasetable, that contains my payload, and after pushing all update-data to this, then creating another endpoint, which tells my WooCommerce store to start working through the list.

Please let me know if there are some excellent way of achieving this.

Comment: have you looked at this? might be too late but we're doing similar tasks through this https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_schedule_event/